# Node JS udp broadcast not read -- node js and iOS

Tags: ios, node.js, udp, broadcast, gcdasyncsocket

here is my code (javascript for node):

```
var dgram = require('dgram');
var message = new Buffer("why hello beautiful");

var client = dgram.createSocket("udp4");
client.bind(41234);
client.setBroadcast(true);
client.send(message, 0, message.length, 41234, "134.71.147.255");

console.log('msg sent');

client.close();
```

here is the ifconfig for my computer running node (the only pertinent thing I think -- correct me if im wrong please):

```
inet addr:134.71.146.49  Bcast:134.71.147.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

The udp broacast is neither recieved on my iOS app nor visible through a packet inspector. 
What is going wrong?! The iOS app uses the GCDAsyncUdpSocket framework:

```
- (void) initUDPlistener {
    NSLog(@"initUDPlistener");

    udpSocket = [[GCDAsyncUdpSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![udpSocket bindToPort:UDP_PORT error:&error]) //does the port matter? i dont know
    {
        return;
    }
    if (![udpSocket beginReceiving:&error])
    {
        return;
    }

    [udpSocket enableBroadcast:YES error:nil];
    [udpSocket sendData:[self pack:@"iOS to bcast"] toHost:UDP_BCAST_ADDR port:UDP_PORT withTimeout:-1 tag:0];


}



#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Delegate UDP methods


- (void)udpSocket:(GCDAsyncUdpSocket *)sock didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
      fromAddress:(NSData *)address
withFilterContext:(id)filterContext

{
    NSLog(@"niets."); 
    NSString *msg = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    if (msg)
    {
        NSLog(@"iets gekregen");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error convertion");

    }

    NSLog(@"HMMMM");

}

-(void) udpSocket:(GCDAsyncUdpSocket *) sock didSendDataWithTag:(long)tag {//called. and packet inspector recieves the packet when it is sent OUT from the iOS app. 

    NSLog(@"written data tag: %ld", tag);
}

-(void) udpSocket:(GCDAsyncUdpSocket *)sock didConnectToAddress:(NSData *)address { //never called

    NSLog(@"connected to some address");
}
```

What happens:
"didReceiveData" does not get called from the node broadcast. It gets called when it sends its own message out, however.

the iOS app, on the other hand, successfully broadcasts and i am able to intercept that packet on my packet inspector.  The same packet inspector does not show packets that should be originating from Node, however.

what am I doing wrong in node?  I think what I am doing in node is the problem.